# Back Button is not appearing properly on navigation bar iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

i have been developing an iOS app. In that app i had segue from a ViewController A to ViewController B. When i moved from A to B, the back button appeared fine then i added another Segue from ViewController C to B and still the back button on B is fine. But then i added a Segue from another ViewController D to B and the back button misplaced. It appeared fallen down. Let me show you how it looks.
[image: This is how it looked after three Segues]

This happened after i added three segues to the same ViewController from three different ViewControllers.
Please let me know where i am doing wrong and how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Can't think of any reason other than any custom appearance/code you set in **ViewController D**

Comment: double check viewcontroller D!

Comment: Why D to B, why not D to C?

Comment: Please show code for adding back button

Comment: There is no code to set the back button of the view controller.
It is just moved from one controller to another and the back button is automatically there.